# Beneficial proofs of work

Tags: security, proof-of-work, proof-of-stake, authentication

I'm new to this community and a Bitcoin novice.

I believe to have understood the concept and purpose of [proof of work](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Proof_of_work) but also, that the high energy consumption of proofs of work is a major problem of the Bitcoin (and other blockchain based) systems.

The puzzle that need to be solved for the proof of work has to be complex:

- computing the [cryptographic nonce](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cryptographic_nonce) (as used in the Bitcoin system)
- solving complex differential equations
- operations on dense matrices

I wonder if my impression is correct that these puzzles' only purpose is to provide authentication, esp. for the right to mine new bitcoins -  and that they are otherwise "useless".

More than that I wonder if there are attempts to define complex proof of work puzzles that fulfill other purposes that are more beneficial/useful/valuable to - let's say society - which would justify the high energy consumption.

You may compare this with Google's [ReCAPTCHAs](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ReCAPTCHA) that next to authentication "assist in the digitization of books or improve machine learning".

Answer (score 1):

Your first point is indeed right: The BTC puzzle is only useful for ensuring the security of the blockchain.

Onto your next question: One of the first attempts to define a "useful" PoW was [Primecoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primecoin), created back in 2013. Additional research in this area [is being done](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/203.pdf).

In defense of Bitcoin's PoW, some people have said that Bitcoin mining tends to use up energy that would otherwise go to waste. For instance, if a hydroelectric plant is no longer being used for its original industrial purposes, then it can instead be harnessed for BTC mining. Mining on fossil fuels is currently unprofitable.

Of course, a more "useful" PoW could harness this energy for something even better. But even then you have to weigh up the pros and cons of switching BTC/ETH to such a PoW function. And you'll probably come up short.

Comment: Why should a hydroelectric plant no longer be used? Energy plants are expensive, energy is expensive - so why should energy go to waste anywhere in the world?

Comment: Hydroelectric plants produce energy regardless of whether there is demand for it. Some of it can go to waste. The energy *could* be stored in batteries and released on demand, but I don't know how practical that is.

Comment: Additionally, it's easy for BTC miners to "move in" and soak up unused energy

Comment: What do you mean with "move in"?

Comment: ship the ASIC equipment and start mining

Comment: For example to Africa or India? Ship the equipment and pay for "energy mining" rights?